# Use $http data in service

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to create a small mobile invoice application to view invoices, update them and manage client data.

Therefor i want to create a service, that first loads all the invoices via an API and then make it accessible by all other service methods.

For example: `myService.getInvoices()` should load all invoices with a $http request and return them. `myService.getInvoices(id)` should return a single invoice. If getInvoices(id) is called first, it should load all invoices first ($http) and then return the particular one.

Now for the tricky part. I want to edit the invoices inside the app. When saving the invoice data should simply be updatet in the service and THEN a $http post request should send the data to the api. This way the invoices list should always stay updated without any need to completely reload the invoices from the api. The same way new invoices should be inserted.

In summary: the app should be able to work offline after loading all invoices one time. Only the first load, updates and inserts should perform any requests.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You should look into utilizing angular's `$resource` factory (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)  it has a lot of  useful built in methods for dealing with APIs

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are assuming the changes are not going to happen anywhere other than mobile app. an app that needs to load the data once, that's likely inaccurate.

However, to answer your question, you can always update the model inside the service, send the update request, and return. All HTTP requests are asynchronous. The users will not have to wait for them.

If you want something really advanced, with proper offline model cache, you can try something like breezeJS ([more about offline features](http://www.getbreezenow.com/hybrid-apps)) which can work fine with AngularJS ([more about Angular support](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/breeze-angular.html)).

Answer (score 0):

You could create a factory/service that retrieve the data from the request and then re-use the stored data wherever you need to:

```
module.factory('myService', function ($http) {
   var invoiceValues;

   // this will make a http request and store the result
   var requestInvoiceValues = function() {
    $http.get("/api/getInvoices").then(
        function(results){
            invoiceValues = results;
        });
  };

  // call the stored result, returning all invoices(without making a http request)
  var getInvoices = function() {
    return invoiceValues;
  };

  // call stored result, returning filtered values
  var getInvoiceById = function(id) {
    var filteredValues;
    // TODO: filter values logic using 'invoiceValues'
    return filteredValues;
  };

   return{
     requestInvoiceValues : requestInvoiceValues, 
     getInvoices : getInvoices,
     getInvoiceById : getInvoiceById 
   }

});
```

You can now call `getInvoiceValues` whenever you need to retreive these. Whenever you nedd to update the invoice values from the server you simply need to call `requestInvoiceValues`. Note that you need to call `requestInvoiceValues` at some stage before you call `getInvoiceValues` to populate the invoices.

```
myApp.controller('MyController', function ($scope, myService) {
  var init = function (){
    myService.requestInvoiceValues(); // this will make the http request to the server       
  };

  var justGetValues = function(){
    $scope.items = myService.getInvoices(); // this will get the result (without making a http request)
  };

});
```

Comment: Thanks! That's helpful. Instead of calling the requestInvoiceValues() anywhere outside the service itself i thought i could call it everytime a controller wants to get data from it. With that there wouldn't be any need to "preload" the data on app start. However, what would be the best place to call the myService.requestInvoiceValues() the first time to load the data from the server?

Comment: That is entirely up to you, but if this is data you know you will be using I'd probably run it as soon as possible in the 'invoiceController'. Since all calls are async there are no guarantees that the `requestInvoiceValues()` is finished when you need it, but since it is returning a promise you can chain it in a `then()`